# Get column names when summarising a data table using multiple functions in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table that has multiple columns.  A short reproducible example of the same is as follows:

```
 library(data.table)
 DT = setDT(structure(list(ZONE = c("WEST", "WEST", "WEST", "EAST", "EAST", 
"EAST", "EAST"), PULSES = c(347, 70, 110, 720, 280, 190, 35), 
    FRUITS = c(172, 130, 0, 578, 350, 220, 50), CEREALS = c(740, 
    639, 149, 1381, 2415, 1765, 525), newmlt = c(8248, 838.5, 
    287.75, 46, 60.375, 38.81, 38.81)), .Names = c("ZONE", "PULSES", 
"FRUITS", "CEREALS", "newmlt"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame")))
```

I am trying to summarise multiple columns(dynamically changing) of data frame producing multiple summaries by applying different functions on the same column.  For example:the following are some of the functions:

Function to % of non-zeros

```
usrs <- function(x) round(length(x[x != 0])/length(x)*100,0)
```

wrapping it up with a mean

```
my.summary = function(x) list(MEAN = mean(x), 'USERS_%' = usrs(x))
```

Selecting the columns for summarisation

```
cols <- c('PULSES', 'CEREALS')
```

using data.table

```
cerr <- DT[, unlist(lapply(.SD, my.summary)), .SDcols = cols, by = ZONE]
cerr
```

The group by option also dynamically changes.
However, I am not getting the column names using above code.  How do I get the column name also along with the Zone and V1.

I also tried `setkey(DT, ZONE)` and used `by = .EACHI` - but getting NA for my usrs function.

My desired output is as follows:

```
   ZONE     COL         V1
1: WEST MEAN.PULSES   175.6667
2: WEST usrs.PULSES   100.0000
3: WEST MEAN.CEREALS  509.3333
4: WEST usrs.CEREALS  100.0000
5: EAST MEAN.PULSES   306.2500
6: EAST usrs.PULSES   100.0000
7: EAST MEAN.CEREALS  1521.5000
8: EAST usrs.CEREALS  100.0000
```

How do I get the columns names too as one of the columns in the output.

Comment: `df[ , c(list(cols), lapply(.SD, my.summary))]`

Comment: I'd suggest `melt(DT[, c("ZONE", cols), with=FALSE], id="ZONE")[, .(m = mean(value), nz = round(mean(value!=0)*100,0)), by=.(ZONE,variable)]` (keep the stats in separate cols...if you really want 'em stacked, can `melt` again).

Comment: @Frank Many thanks...fits perfectly my use case....I can accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest

```
cols <- c('PULSES', 'CEREALS')
melt(DT[, c("ZONE", cols), with=FALSE], id="ZONE")[, 
  .(m = mean(value), nz = round(mean(value!=0)*100, 0))
, by=.(ZONE,variable)]

#    ZONE variable         m  nz
# 1: WEST   PULSES  175.6667 100
# 2: EAST   PULSES  306.2500 100
# 3: WEST  CEREALS  509.3333 100
# 4: EAST  CEREALS 1521.5000 100
```

If you want the data stacked instead of in separate columns, `melt` again.

---

Alternately, you could compute it for all cols and filter afterwards:

```
cols <- c('PULSES', 'CEREALS')
melt(DT, id="ZONE")[, 
  .(m = mean(value), nz = round(mean(value!=0)*100,0))
, by=.(ZONE,variable)][ variable %in% cols ]
```